# HTML page not showing the response received from the server

Tags: angular

I am new to the Angular and trying to build an app which will call and API and the received response will show on UI.

I already tried to use `ng` directives like `*ngFor` , `ng-repeat`.
But response is not displaying on HTML I can see only in the console.

Image of response:
[image: response]

My component.ts

```
import { Component, Pipe, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Testing API';
    private apiUrl = 'https://myurl.com';
    data: any = {};
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello API');
        this.getData();
    }
    header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    ngOnInit() {}
    getData() {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {
            responseType: 'text'
        }).subscribe((data) = >
                console.log(data)));
    }
}
```

Component.html

```html
<html>
   <div style="text-align:center">
      <h1>
         Welcome to {{ title }}!
      </h1>
      <div ng-app="">
         <table>
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>City</th>
                  <th>Gender</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="response in data">
                  <td>{{ response.Name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ response.City }}</td>
                  <td>{{ response.Gender }}</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Your component is from angular but template looks like angularjs

Comment: I tried to change this in angular as well but it sill not showing anything. [Object Object] is coming

Comment: Your console output looks like `data` is an array, Can you show result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: Attaching the link of image. see above.

Comment: It's a string... `data` should be array of objects like `{Name: "somename", City: "somecity", Gender: "F/M"}` and you should replace that `ng-repeat` with `*ngFor="let response of data"`. And I can't see where do you assign your data to `this.data`

Comment: @barbsan Thanks I did this with *ngFor and it is working as expected now.

Comment: I've seen you've accepted one answer with `*ngFor` and then marked the other answer as accepted - was it a mistake? You can accept only one answer, but once you get voting privilege, you can upvote all the answers you found helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not storing anything in data, and you are trying to read from data in your html table.

you have to store your API response in data, and it must be array to loop through in html.

```
 title = 'Testing API';
private apiUrl = 'https://myurl.com';
data: any = [];
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello API');
    this.getData();
}
header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
ngOnInit() {}
getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {
        responseType: 'text'
    }).subscribe((data) = >
           this.data=data;
            console.log(data)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, there's some weird stuff in your code.
You've declared `data` as an empty object in the class but I don't see where you assign the data to this variable. In `getData` method you should do something like this:

```
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {
        responseType: 'text'
    }).subscribe((data) => { this.data = data; }));
```

And in your template you're using AngularJS's `ng-repeat` instead of `*ngFor="let response of data"`. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays, so if you really need `data` to be an object, you can use `KeyValuePipe` which transforms objects into an array of key value pairs:
https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe